# exception raised inside of a map() inside of a try-expect not handled by try-except

Tags: python, python-3.x

Anyone understand how to handle an error inside of a map()? I would like to be able to handle this kind of error without the program crashing.

```
def add_one(val):
    raise Exception('My error!')
    return val+1

values = [1,2,3,4]

# Does not work
try:
    new_values = map(add_one, values)
except:
    new_values = []
print(list(new_values)) # Raises an Exception: My error!

# Works
try:
    new_values = []
    for x in values:
        new_values.append(add_one(x))
except:
    new_values = []
print(new_values) # Returns []
```

Answer (score 1):

`map` is lazy - it doesn't actually consume the data until necessary.

So the two examples you've provided aren't equivalent.

Comment: More explicitly, `add_one` isn't actually called until you try to *retrieve* the first item from the iterable returned by `map`.

Comment: Ok, but how can I handle an error in the map portion? Second example was just for my own sanity to see that the func was working properly. I guess it isn't needed.

Comment: Ah makes total sense @chepner! Was forgetting that the generator doesn't evaluate anything until I call it! Thanks! It was throwing the error OUTSIDE of the try-expect, when I was finally trying to evaluate it.